# How to send SMS messages

Tags: c++, qt, sms

I can't figure out how to send SMS messages to a phone with Qt running on Ubuntu 16.04.

The code below works fine in Windows Visual C++/CLI. Is there an equivalent of this or some equivalent code in Qt on Ubuntu 16.04?

```cs
using namespace System::Net;        //need for Webclient
using namespace System::Net::Mail;  //need for sending SMS text message via email

//send an SMS message via email:
MailAddress^ to = gcnew MailAddress("760xxxxxxx@vmobl.com"); //the generic Virgin Mobile format
MailAddress^ from = gcnew MailAddress("xxxxxxxx@roadrunner.com"); //hosted by Time Warner Cable
MailMessage^ message = gcnew MailMessage(from,to);
message->Subject = "What's up?";    //the subject line
message->Body = Globals::TextMsg;   //TestMsg is a string; the body of the message to be sent
SmtpClient^ client = gcnew SmtpClient;  //create a client
client->Host::set("mail.twc.com");      //the outgoing SMTP mail server of Time Warner
client->Send(message);          //send message to phone
client->~SmtpClient();          //destroy the client
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same operation as above except in Ubuntu (16.04 in my case) with Qt (5.5 in my case), and replace the C# code with C++, do this:

Using the Time-Warner SMTP server (instead of Gmail server):

1. Go to [Github: xcoder123 / SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5](https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/tree/master/smtp)
2. Download, clone or unzip; then open this excellent project in QT
3. Make the following changes in smtp.h:

   - Add this to work with Time Warner Cable:

     ```cpp
     #include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
     ```
   - In public: Smtp change `int port = 465` to `int port = 587`, gmail uses 465, Time Warner uses 587.
   - In private:

     ```cpp
      //QSslSocket *socket;  //this works with Gmail
      QTcpSocket *socket;    //this works with Time Warner Cable
     ```
4. Make the following changes in *smtp.cpp*:

   - In `Smtp::Smtp`:

     ```cpp
     //socket = new QSslSocket(this);  //this works with Gmail
     socket = new QTcpSocket(this);    //this works with Time Warner Cable
     ```
   - In `void Smtp::sendMail`:

     ```cpp
     //socket->connectToHostEncrypted(host, port); //"smtp.gmail.com" and 465 for gmail TLS
     socket->connectToHost(host, port);  //Time Warner doesn't use Encrypted
     ```
   - In `void Smtp::readyRead`

     ```cpp
     //socket->startClientEncryption();  //Time Warner doesn't use Encryption, so comment all this out
     //if(!socket->waitForEncrypted(timeout)) 
     //{
     //qDebug() << socket->errorString();  
     //state = Close;  
     //}
     ```

     ```cpp
     //*t << QByteArray().append(user).toBase64()  << "\r\n";
     *t << QByteArray().append(user)  << "\r\n";  //Time Warner doesn't use base64
     ```

With this, emails can be sent from the UI.

To send a text message to Virgin Mobile, replace recipient with the 10-digit phone number *@vmobl.com*.

Example:

- "7609999999@vmobl.com".

The text message will be "Subject:" plus the subject. The body won't appear so leave it blank. There is no easy way to get rid of "Subject:" at the beginning that I could find.